# Two methods with different signatures, jquery is not calling correct method

Tags: c#, jquery

There are two methods `GetUserAssignedSystems()` and `GetUserAssignedSystems(string Id)`
These methods act very differently from each other.  The problem is, when I want to call `GetUserAssignedSystems(string Id)`, the parameter-less method is called.

Here are the methods:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public IEnumerable GetUserAssignedSystems(string cacId)
{
    return Data.UserManager.GetUserAssingedSystems(cacId);
}

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public IEnumerable GetUserAssignedSystems()
{
    //do something else
}
```

Here is the jQuery making the call:

```
CallMfttService("ServiceLayer/UserManager.asmx/GetUserAssignedSystems", 
        "{'cacId':'" + $('#EditUserCacId').val() + "'}", function(result) {
            for (var userSystem in result.d) {
                $('input[UserSystemID=' + result.d[userSystem] + ']').attr(
                    'checked', 'true');
            }
        });
```

Any ideas why this method is being ignored?

**UPDATE**

Here is the code for the CallMfttService

```
function CallMfttService(method, jsonParameters, successCallback, errorCallback){
if (errorCallback == undefined)
{
    errorCallback = function(xhr)
    {
        if (xhr.status == 501)
        {
            alert(xhr.statusText);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Unexpected Error");
        }
    }
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: method,
    data: jsonParameters,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: successCallback,
    error: errorCallback
});
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript does not support overloaded functions (multiple functions with the same name that accept different parameters) in the same way that some languages do.  If you need it to optionally perform tasks based on the presence of an input parameter you have to add checking within the function that determines if the variable was passed `if ( param == undefined) {}` and then behave in the appropriate way based on the presence or absence of said variable.  Redefining the function twice with different parameters won't work.

Per updates, try changing your call like so:

```
CallMfttService("ServiceLayer/UserManager.asmx/GetUserAssignedSystems", 
    {'cacId': $('#EditUserCacId').val() }, function(result) {
        for (var userSystem in result.d) {
            $('input[UserSystemID=' + result.d[userSystem] + ']').attr(
                'checked', 'true');
        }
    });
```

Essentially you were passing a string, not an object to the jQuery $.ajax method, which was probably preventing your values from reaching the server properly.  Let me know how that behaves.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that you could not have overloaded methods.  When I commented out the parameter-less method everything worked perfect.  Thanks again!

Comment: @g.d.d.c. But is seems like the failure to call the right function is happening at the C# level, not JS. I am not sure removing the other function fixed the problem or simply masked it.

Comment: @Doug - I was about to go out and buy a new javascript book because it sure didn't look like js to me. Unless perhaps those functions generate equivalent javascript functions that are sent to the client.

Comment: @doug-neiner Can you elaborate a little bit further?  I'm not terribly familiar with the correlation between the C# functions and your JS functions.  Does CallMfttService launch an AJAX Request and pass in the parameters to your C# function?  Can your C# function be modified to contain checking for the presence of the cacID variable?  C#'s not my strong suit per se, but if you can provide some more code I can try to help further.

Comment: @doug-neiner Not sure if me changing the post updates you, but I know this comment will flag you.  I think the trouble was with how you were passing the parameters to jQuery's ajax method.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you mean to send JSON, or a normal object literal. But in the first case, your JSON is invalid... JSON needs double quotes around strings and keys:

```
 CallMfttService("ServiceLayer/UserManager.asmx/GetUserAssignedSystems", '{"cacId":"' + $('#EditUserCacId').val() + '"}', function(result) {
```

Without knowing what `CallMfttService` does, its hard to say, but I would def try this as well:

```
CallMfttService("ServiceLayer/UserManager.asmx/GetUserAssignedSystems", {cacId:   $('#EditUserCacId').val()}, function(result) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue where the correct C# WebMethod is not getting called. I am getting a "Resource Not Found Error". It appears that for whatever reason (I am not sure why exactly, maybe someone else can elaborate), the WebMethod Class does not like overloaded methods. It is incorrectly interpreting the type of the passed parameters. If I remove all of the overloaded methods in the C# WebMethod Class and leave just one, regardless of which one I leave behind, it will now get called and work as expected.